# STM32: Flash vs. SRAM

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash

I'm trying to understand if the SRAM in the STM32 is solely for speeding up the execution, or it is also considered additional storage.

Take STM32G031 as an example with 32KB flash and 8KB SRAM, and assume the compiled binary has following:

- 16KB .text
- 4KB .bss
- 4KB .data
- 4KB .rodata

Is it correct that (.text + .bss + .data + .rodata) needs to be smaller than 32KB to fit into the flash, and during boot sequence the .bss and .data are copied into the SRAM?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  On a flash-based MCU the primary purpose of SRAM is to store things which must be modified at runtime.  A chip with some SRAM on the code-priority path could also use it for execution speed but one with it on the data-priority path could not.

Comment: Why does not make sense? Is perfectly reasonable wondering this. Under the eyes of many starting with MCUs, sometimes is not obvious to consider that during binary preparation, what is going to be copied into SRAM is part of the flash. In the startup phase, such content like .data is copied into SRAM. Is perfectly possible to modify things at run-time in flash, just deeply inconvenient. So yes, all of the sum has to be smaller than the FLASH.

Answer (score 5):

The .data segment is copied into RAM, but .bss is usually just set to zero and thus does *not* occupy any flash memory.

Thus the flash size must be >= .text + .rodata + .data bytes.

Comment: Ah okay, this makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: .rodata and .data are separate output sections from the compiler .data does not live in .rodata they are completely separate.  There generally isnt a use case to copy .rodata to ram and that would not solve your .data problem as they are two independent sections.

Comment: The .rodata section is copied to RAM only on AVR platform, because the architecture cannot handle pointers to flash in 16 bits. ARM Cortex-M generally keeps this in flash unless one uses unusual startup code.

Answer (score 3):

Now, first off the terms .data, .text, .bss have historical context, but they are just labels, the toolchain authors are not bound by them and can choose.  But assuming we are talking about gnu tools here (gcc and binutils) then yes they use those terms along with .rodata

.text  this is the code basically, the program, the machine code and some associated data that is tied to it.  It is considered read-only and can live in flash/rom or ram depending on the programmers choices, target platform, etc.

.data this is read/write data so it needs to be in ram, but for a microcontroller (implied by stm32 tag) there is no operating system to load this into ram, from a non-volatile media like an hard disk so this needs to have a copy in flash/rom and get copied to ram for use by the bootstrap.  For a program that runs on an operating system the bootstrap can do this or the operating systems loader can do it when it reads the file and places items in memory

.bss this is read/write data that is assumed to be initialized to zero.  This lives in ram.  because its contents are all zero it is not necessary to keep a full copy of it in flash only the start address and size or start and end addresses are required.  Programmers choice.

.rodata, depending on the linker and script you wont see this, but this is read only data that lives in flash, similar to .text but data not code.

The linker script and where things are buried are programmers choice for the most part but dont confuse the compiler output (.text, .rodata, .data, .bss, etc) and where they live in memory (flash or sram).  .rodata lives in flash ideally, .data is separate and a copy is in flash for mcu code to work but .data is neither in .text nor .rodata it is in the same flash memory space as the other two, but they are all three separately packed in there.  You certainly do not copy .rodata to sram normally.

so take this application

```
unsigned int data=5;
unsigned int zero;
const unsigned int con=7;
static unsigned int stat=11;
int notmain ( void )
{
    return(3);
}
```

this bootstrap

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x20001000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

hello:
.word __data_rom_start__
.word __data_start__
.word __data_end__
.word __data_size__
.word __bss_start__
.word __bss_end__
.word __bss_size__
```

and this linker script

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
   .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > bob
   __data_rom_start__ = .;
   .data : {
    __data_start__ = .;
    *(.data*)
   } > ted AT > bob
   __data_end__ = .;
   __data_size__ = __data_end__ - __data_start__;
   .bss  : {
   __bss_start__ = .;
   *(.bss*)
   } > ted
   __bss_end__ = .;
   __bss_size__ = __bss_end__ - __bss_start__;
}
```

Intentionally not using names like flash and sram or ram and rom because these are just labels.

```
   .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
```

The first .text is also just a label you can replace it and it all still works

```
   .banana : { *(.text*) } > bob
```

A disassembly of the C code shows the sections that the compiler chose:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <notmain>:
   0:   2003        movs    r0, #3
   2:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <data>:
   0:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00000000 <con>:
   0:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7
```

and that is exactly as expected.  the initialized global goes in .data, the uninitialized goes in .bss and the read only global goes in .rodata.  And the code in .text.  the static global stat goes away (optimized) because it is dead code, unused.

The bootstrap:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
   4:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <notmain>
   c:   e7ff        b.n e <hang>

0000000e <hang>:
   e:   e7fe        b.n e <hang>

00000010 <hello>:
    ...
```

because it was written that way all of it is .text, you will sometimes find folks have a strong desire to create a new .init or other name of a section so that they can in the linker put this code first as it has the vector table the stm32 needs to boot with.  Could just learn the tools and not need to do that.

So now link it.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f810   bl  800002c <notmain>
 800000c:   e7ff        b.n 800000e <hang>

0800000e <hang>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <hang>

08000010 <hello>:
 8000010:   08000034    stmdaeq r0, {r2, r4, r5}
 8000014:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
 8000018:   20000004    andcs   r0, r0, r4
 800001c:   00000004    andeq   r0, r0, r4
 8000020:   20000004    andcs   r0, r0, r4
 8000024:   20000008    andcs   r0, r0, r8
 8000028:   00000004    andeq   r0, r0, r4

0800002c <notmain>:
 800002c:   2003        movs    r0, #3
 800002e:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .rodata:

08000030 <con>:
 8000030:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7

Disassembly of section .data:

20000000 <data>:
20000000:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000004 <zero>:
20000004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

and this is our whole program.  We asked that read only items be placed in flash (0x08000000 is the app flash space for most/all stm32s some have an alternate) and for the read/write items to live in sram starting at 0x20000000 and they are there.

Note that this is using the disassembler objdump so it tries to disassemble everything:

```
20000004 <zero>:
20000004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

that is not an andeq instruction it is just a data item/value

```
20000004 <zero>:
20000004:   00000000
```

I didnt actually do the full bootstrap but placed the linker created variables/labels in this so we could see them:

```
08000010 <hello>:
 8000010:   08000034   __data_rom_start__
 8000014:   20000000   __data_start__
 8000018:   20000004   __data_end__
 800001c:   00000004   __data_size__
 8000020:   20000004   __bss_start__
 8000024:   20000008   __bss_end__
 8000028:   00000004   __bss_size__
```

so the flash/rom copy of the .data starts at 08000034 and is 00000004 bytes long, it lands in memory at 20000000.  the start of bss is 20000004 and is 00000004 bytes long and with that we can initialize ram from this flash image.

Looking at the binary in this form (motorola s-record):

```
S00F00006E6F746D61696E2E737265631F
S31508000000001000200900000800F010F8FFE7FEE7DE
S31508000010340000080000002004000020040000004E
S315080000200400002008000020040000000320704798
S3090800003007000000B7
S3090800003405000000B5
S70508000000F2
```

Here is our .data in the binary

```
S30908000034 05000000 B5
```

That would get copied to ram.

.rodata is a compiler thing

so a gnu linker script line like this

.rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > bob

is saying declare an output binary section named .rodata and fill it with items from all objects that have a section name that starts with .rodata, so if any of the objects in the order they are processed by the linker (which if no file names are declared in the linker script then the command line determines order thus no need to play games with the linker script) so if there is a .rodata_pickle in some code it will go here as well as the .rodata that we generated from the C compiler above.  The .rodata name on the left is an output section but where it lives in memory is bob.  Now it is true that within this declaration you could put *(.data*) as well and pile them into the same memory section but that would make no sense because now you are wasting ram with a copy of rodata that never needs to live in ram except perhaps for performance.

.data does not live in nor is it associated with .rodata, you dont copy .rodata to ram normally that would just be a waste of ram.

Now if you are like me then I prefer this

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00200000, LENGTH = 0x1000 /*ITCM*/
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}


unsigned int data;
unsigned int zero;
const unsigned int con=7;
static unsigned int stat;
int notmain ( void )
{
    data=5;
    zero=0;
    stat=11;
    return(3);
}



Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <notmain>
 800000c:   e7ff        b.n 800000e <hang>

0800000e <hang>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <hang>

08000010 <notmain>:
 8000010:   4903        ldr r1, [pc, #12]   ; (8000020 <notmain+0x10>)
 8000012:   2005        movs    r0, #5
 8000014:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (8000024 <notmain+0x14>)
 8000016:   2200        movs    r2, #0
 8000018:   6008        str r0, [r1, #0]
 800001a:   2003        movs    r0, #3
 800001c:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
 800001e:   4770        bx  lr
 8000020:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
 8000024:   20000004    andcs   r0, r0, r4

Disassembly of section .rodata:

08000028 <con>:
 8000028:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000000 <data>:
20000000:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

20000004 <zero>:
20000004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Yes this can burn more flash, but that depends.  Then of course there is the whole dont use globals thing which is a bad rule, esp for embedded work like an MCU, you want to control your memory usage and the stack is definitely not the way to do that.  But that turns into a hot topic so choose your own path there.  If you dont use globals then you dont need to bother with .data and .bss and much of this conversation/question goes away (as well as toolchain specific stuff like linker scripts which is why I write this way to avoid as much toolchain specific stuff as I can, more portable, easier to read, maintain, etc..IMO).

---

This output here though is the answer to your whole question

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <notmain>:
   0:   2003        movs    r0, #3
   2:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <data>:
   0:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00000000 <con>:
   0:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7
```

gcc and many others .text is the code and associated read only data.  .rodata is read only data.  .data is initialized (non-zero) global or local global (static local) data.  .bss is uninitialized (assumed zero but some compilers will warn you) data.

.text and .rodata for an mcu dont need to leave flash, that is their home.  .data needs to have non-volatile storage but live in ram.  Before the C entry point you need to copy it to its linked address in ram.  .bss is zeros so no need to waste flash with a bunch of zeros, the start address and size are all that need to live in non-volatile storage though, and it needs to be zeroed before calling the C entry point.

So your flash would normally be consumed with

```
.text + .rodata + .data + .bss size and offset + padding
```

Ram is filled by

```
.data + .bss + whatever your code does (a heap if you dare to use malloc on an mcu (use .data and .rodata and .bss instead)) + stack if your mcu uses the same ram for this.
```

How all this comes together is toolchain dependent and not assumed to be portable.
To be general purpose and widely usable the linker needs an elaborate system to allow the developer enough control over the output binary to create applications for target systems.  And the linker solution and bootstrap solution along with the rules for the target system are married together in a toolchain plus target system way (not expected to be portable but you get lucky sometimes).  Meaning how you write the bootstrap (in asm obviously) and find the sizes of items to copy or zero, depends on the toolchain and the marriage between the assembler and the linker and linker script or whatever the linker uses.